# track and rail in Portuguese

Tags: vocabulário

What would you call "track" and "rail" in Portuguese? Track is the whole thing, while a rail is one of the two long pieces of metal where the train lays its wheels, e.g. the right rail.

track:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/zL5aEWRzgSt719K4V_TSOdIN49ZTdyGHEB0B0ZX5un-iDIEyJfQ-m0JqhW1f4ytN2Iw=w300

[image: a track, seen from a front-side section]

rail:
http://www.ikonet.com/es/diccionariovisual/images/esp/corte-de-un-rail-117780.jpg
[image: a trail]

Could they be:

- track - trilho m, linha f
- rail - trilho

Comment: You should add sample sentences to your question. It would be a stronger question.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of railways, *rail* is [*carril*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/carril) (especially in Portugal) or [*trilho*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/TRILHO) (especially in Brazil), whereas *track* is [*caminho de ferro*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/caminho-de-ferro), [*via férrea*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/via%20f%C3%A9rrea), [*ferrovia*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ferrovia) or [*linha (férrea/de trem/de comboio)*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/linha). To refer to a short section of rail track you can also just say ***carris*** or ***trilhos***, which is the plural of *carril* and *trilho*.

*Caminho de ferro* is more like *railway*, so often referring to the whole system. *Via férrea* and *ferrovia* are more likely to be found in print than in casual speech. *Linha* is a commonly used word in both print and speech. It is a rather versatile word. It can refer to a whole railway line between two cities, or to a metro line; but it can simply refer to any section of railtrack, as in the following examples taken from the press:

> Policial salva mulher que tentava se jogar na **linha do trem** com bebê
>   [(*O Dia*, Rio, 2016.)](http://odia.ig.com.br/noticia/rio-de-janeiro/2016-03-12/policial-salva-mulher-que-tentava-se-jogar-na-linha-do-trem-com-bebe.html)
>
> **5** Se a cancela abaixar e o seu carro estiver parado sobre a **linha do trem**, saia do veículo e se afaste do local.
>   [...]
>   **7** Cuidado com a velocidade na hora de atravessar a **linha férrea**, porque você precisa manter o controle do carro no caso de emergência.
>   [(“O que fazer se o carro enguiçar na linha do trem?” Via Certa, Natal RN.)](http://www.viacertanatal.com/2013/03/o-que-fazer-se-o-carro-enguicar-na.html)

[image]
[“Alguns passageiros chegaram a sentar e a deitar na **linha férrea** impedindo a passagem de trens”, O Globo, Rio](http://oglobo.globo.com/rio/tumulto-em-oswaldo-cruz-apos-problema-em-trem-3459961)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that, in Brazilian Portuguese, `track` assumes a plural form, `trilhos`, while `rail` is called `trilho`. So, we do use the same word, differing only in number. This holds true even when targeting highly technical audiences. For instance, I took this picture from one of my engineering classes (the course was Organization of Industrial Services):

[image: A transversal scheme of a track]

In European Portuguese, they're called `carril` for `rail` and `carris` for `track`, in a similar fashion.

Comment: Ah vocês não dizem *carril* aí no Brasil?

Comment: @Jacinto Eu, particularmente, nunca havia ouvido ou lido esta palavra antes. Só a descobri porque procurei na Wikipédia se vocês usavam algum termo diferente de `trilho`.

Comment: Formidável! Assim os vosso trens nunca podem descarrilar :)